# Is there any real benefit to upgrade a SharePoint 2013 Enterprise Farm from SQL Server 2014 to SQL Server 2016?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sql-server, upgrade

Our DBA told us that he wants to upgrade it's Microsoft SQL Server Enterprise 2014 to SQL Server 2016 Enterprise.
As we are running our SharePoint Enterprise 2013 Farm in those SQL 2014 instances, we want to know if there's really an advantage for SharePoint 2013 to run with the latest SQL 2016 Server, because we've recently (lats year) gone through a migration of our Web Applications from SQL Server 2012 Enterprise to SQL Server 2014, and albeit not much time was needed as we thought, it comes with a lot of testing and deploying time involved.

I've read about some SRSS benefits with the latest SQL Server Enterprise 2016, but with a SharePoint 2013 Enterprise Farm, I would like to know from any of you SharePoint gurus out there whether it is worth the effort and time, and of course if maybe there's any risk involved.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server 2016 will not be supported by SharePoint 2010 or 2013. Microsoft's policy for SQL Server is when SharePoint is released, it supports the current version of SQL Server (SQL 2012 for SharePoint 2013) +1 (SQL Server 2014), aka N+1.

So, while it may work (or may not depending on SQL Server removed features), Microsoft will not support you should they find SQL Server 2016 containing SharePoint 2013 databases.

Offical reference: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ronalg/2016/06/13/sharepoint-20132016-and-sql-server-2016-supportability-with-ssrs-fun-facts/

Comment: Hi @Trevor, thanks for the answer, do you have any link or official reference about this? I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I've added a link to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

As far I know, Sql server 2016 is not supported with sharepoint 2013.

> At this time, SQL Server 2016 RTM is not supported.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485.aspx#section4

Comment: hey, thanks for the answer, although not supported yet, I remember that we were able to use SQL Server 2014 before when it still was unsupported, did you had that scenario yet?

Comment: Personally, I would not do it for production as it is supported.2nd as sql 16 is new product, not too much testing have been done from end user and less community support.so I will avoid it